# Impact of Git's use of SHA-1?

Tags: sha-1

Git uses SHA-1, and it is common to sign Git commit or tag hashes to authenticate a repo.  Is this insecure now?

Comment: You are talking about GPG signed commits and tags, right?

Comment: @mikeazo yes, GPG signed

Comment: How does [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/67920/2651) not answer your question? Note that Git is very much applied crypto...

Comment: It does answer my question.